# ExtJS this.store.getCount after populating combos

Tags: extjs

Hi I got trouble with ext JS.
Im populating one combo from another.
The first time I select an item from the fist combo it populates the second one (menu)< i select something from the second and I will populate a third one, but when I change the first combo again it will clear the second combo but if I click it I get this error:

> "Error: this.store.getCount is not a function Source File:
>   .../Presentation/Lib/Js/ext-all.js"

Does anyon got a clue of why its happening?

Thank you very much!

```
                    {
                        xtype        : 'combo',
                        store        : cmb_sistemas,
                        hiddenName   : 'id_sistema',
                        allowBlank   : false, 
                        mode         : 'local',
                        fieldLabel   : 'Sistemas',
                        disabled     : true,
                        name         : 'sistemas',
                        id           : 'sistemas',
                        anchor       : '90%',
                        displayField : 'sistema',
                        triggerAction: 'all',  
                        emptyText: 'Select system',
                        editable     : false, 
                        valueField   : 'id',
                        listeners    : {
                                        select: function (){    
                                            idSistema = this.getValue();        
                                            nombreSistema = this.getRawValue();  

                                            cmb_menu = getMenu(idSistema);   
                                            menu = Ext.getCmp("menus");     

                                            menu.store.removeAll();//rdiaz  
                                            menu.clearValue();                             

                                            menu.store = cmb_menu;      //alert("sist: "+this.store.getCount());        
                                            menu.enable();                      
                                        }                                            
                        }
                    },  
                    {
                        xtype        : 'combo',
                        store        : [['0', 'Select']],
                        hiddenName   : 'id',
                        valueField   : 'id',
                        mode         : 'local',
                        allowBlank   : false,
                        fieldLabel   : 'menu',
                        disabled     : true,
                        triggerAction: 'all',
                        emptyText    : 'Seleccione un menu',
                        editable     : false, 
                        name         : 'menus',
                        id           : 'menus',
                        anchor       : '90%',
                        displayField : 'menu',
                        listeners    : {
                                        select: function () {                                           
                                                selectedMenu = this.getValue();                       
                                                cmb_items    = getItemsMenu(selectedMenu, idSistema);  
                                                items    = Ext.getCmp("items");               
                                                items.clearValue();                                 

                                                items.store = cmb_items;  //alert("menu: "+this.store.getCount());
                                                items.enable();
                                        }

                        }
                    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just assigning store to the combo try to use `combo.bindStore(store)` method